# Find side length of square with two points on $x$-axis and other two points on parabola $f(x)=2x^2+6x+\frac12$

Tags: geometry, functions

> Two points of the square are on the X axis. The second two points of the square are on the graph of quadratic function: $f(x)=2x^2+6x+\dfrac{1}{2}$. Find the side length of the square.

I tried to find coordinates of the points with the given equality but I couldn't. Deep explanation would be grateful.

Also note that calculus or any software like Desmos is not allowed!

Comment: well, at a fixed $y$ value (above the vertex of the parabola) there is a width between the two intersections of the horizontal line with the parabola.  For some choice of $y$ this width matches $|y| \; . \;$ Let's see, no Desmos, but this is a good problem for graphing by hand; https://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Comment: I have graphed it by hand but I couldn't solve it anyway. I don't know how to solve for coordinates of the square.

Comment: not hard.... you can find the answer(s) without any algebra, just draw a careful plot, draw some rectangles with two endpoints on the graph and two on the x-axis.

Comment: Hint: the entire construction should be symmetric with respect to reflection relative to the axis of the parabola $x=-\frac{3}{2}$ so $|f\left(-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{a}{2}\right)|=|f\left(-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right)|=|a|$

Answer (score 3):

Let $p$ be the $x$-coordinates of the vertical sides of the  square. Given its two vertexes on the $x$-axis and the other two on the parabola with symmetry around $x=-\frac32$. we have

$$2p^2+6p+\dfrac{1}{2} = \pm2 |p+\frac32|$$

Solve to obtain $p_{1,2}=-\frac12,-\frac52$ and $p_{1,2} =\frac12,-\frac72$. Thus, the side length is $p_1-p_2$, which yields $2$ and $4$.

[image]

Comment: I didn't get how did you get RHS of the equation. Can you explain more deeply?

Comment: @NikaChelidze - the midpoint coordinate is $-3/2$ and $2|p+3/2| $ is then the side length. (a typo of a factor 2 is added; the results given remain correct.)